# highcharter: capture currently selected min and max dates in stock plot

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

I'm developing a Shiny app that uses `highcharter` pkg for data vis. I want to synchronise 2 `highchart` plots so that when I change a date range in one plot (using range selector at the bottom of the plot, not range selector buttons), the second plot applies them, too. I read about `afterSetExtremes()` JS function that captures min and max dates (example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nvk3s/3/) ) that was suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24799617), but I'm not sure how I can apply this JS code to my R/Shiny code.

Below is a simple example of two `highchart` plots that should be in sync

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)


data(fdeaths)
data(mdeaths)


ui <- fluidPage(
  highchartOutput('f_plot'),
  highchartOutput('m_plot')
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$f_plot <- renderHighchart(
    highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
      hc_add_series(fdeaths)

  )

  output$m_plot <- renderHighchart(
    highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
      hc_add_series(mdeaths) 
  )


}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes event to fire the function that will update extremes of the second chart every time we change extremes of the first one. Of course, you can adapt this logic to change the extremes of the first chart when dragging the second one or do the same with a bigger amount of charts.

This is an example of how to do this in pure JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yg50ue1c/

And here you have an R implementation:

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)


data(fdeaths)
data(mdeaths)


ui <- fluidPage(
  highchartOutput('f_plot'),
  highchartOutput('m_plot')
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$f_plot <- renderHighchart(
    highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
      hc_add_series(fdeaths) %>% 
      hc_xAxis(
        events = list(
          afterSetExtremes = JS("function(e) {
            Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max);
          }")
        )
      )
    )

  output$m_plot <- renderHighchart(
    highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
      hc_add_series(mdeaths) %>% 
      hc_xAxis(
        events = list(
          afterSetExtremes = JS("function(e) {
            Highcharts.charts[1].xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max);
          }")
        )
      )
  )

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that Shiny differs a little and changes the order of charts so the second chart instance can be found here: Highcharts.charts[0] but the first here: Highcharts.charts[1]
I wonder what the order would be if we had more charts...

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: hej hej! :) My idea was to capture date ranges from plot one, save it as reactive object in Shiny so that it's accessible by the second chart. Would the above code work in `hc_plotOptions` example like in https://redoakstrategic.com/javascript_r_click_events/? If so, then I'd only need to understand how to set the defined ranges using `hc_rangeSelector()` in R with JS.. hope it makes sense!

Comment: Actually, I made it work! Your link made me digging into that and while I was testing a few things I noticed that... Highcharts.charts[1] is not a second chart but the first one. The second chart is Highcharts.chart[0]... welcome to Shiny (???).
I will edit my answer soon. Pozdrowienia z Krakowa ;)

Comment: whoop whoop! well done and looking forward to seeing your take on the solution :) pozdrawiam z Londynu!

Comment: any luck with the solution? Was looking forward to seeing how you managed to get it to work!

Comment: I edited my answer on Thursday. Could you copy the code from the answer and check if it works?

Comment: fantastic, thank you! I can see that currently the second plot;s range changes according to the first one. Is there a way of making the ranges mutually dependent, i.e. also change the first range according to the second one? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sure, it's easy to implement ;) I will provide you with the answer by the end of the day!

Comment: I edited my answer. Both charts should be mutually dependent now. Let me know if this is what you've been trying to achieve

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was after! big thanks for your help!